# Updating countdown number without interrupting user input

Tags: c#, console

So I have a console game application which generates a random string of x length and the user has to input the same random string before time runs out or they lose.The time is just an int which is held in Game class. Here is the class I use to draw the template:

```
class Template
{
    public static void DrawGameplay() //draws gameplay screen , the main method used to print
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=====================BOMB DEFUSE========================");

        if (Game.level < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("====================== Level {0} =========================", Game.level);

            if(Game.level < 6)
            {
                Body(16);
            }
            else
            {
                Body(13);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Game.level == 10) //10 special case
            {
                Console.WriteLine("====================== Level {0} ========================", Game.level);

                Body(13);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("====================== Level {0} ========================", Game.level);

                Body(11);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void TimeLine() //draws the time line in the middle , feeds drawgameplay
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if (Game.time > 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("====================== Time: {0} ========================", Game.time);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("====================== Time: {0} =========================", Game.time);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void Body(int spaces) //prints everything under the top (game title and lvl) , feeds drawgameplay
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Words.Spaces(spaces);

        Game.PrintList();

        TimeLine();

        Words.Spaces(spaces);
    }
}
```

Then I have this player class:

```
class Player
{
    public static List<char> inputList = new List<char>(); //the list of inputted chars that is used to compare to the defuse code
    static char[] arrayChar;
    static string typed;

    public static void GetInputList() //populates list with letters person typed during time
    {
        typed = Console.ReadLine();
        typed.TrimEnd(); //Gets rid of any extra spaces at the end
        arrayChar = typed.ToArray();
        inputList = arrayChar.ToList();
    }

    public static void Print() // prints inputed letters
    {
        foreach (var letter in inputList)
        {
            Console.Write(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so I can update the time visual as the timer counts down without interfering with the users input? Right now I have the timeline visual in between the randomly generated string and the users input. Thanks for looking.

Comment: The last time I solved similar problems was in the time of DOS. You can not use `Console.ReadLine()` to read user input, since this function will block the code execution *(until function is finished)*. I'm not sure whether there is a `KeyPressed` function, but as far as I remember, there is a `ReadKey` function to read only a single character. The problem can be also solved by using OS native function, but you do not specify used OS and/or portability.

Comment: This is one of those things that is absolute trivial in proper a GUI or Game Design Project. And incredibly hard to impossible in a Console Application. If your longterm goal is actually game development, console and even GUI technologies will not do. You will need anything with a game loop and with .NET Core you have at least 3 options. If you do not want to go into game development, you should just accept that the design as a bad idea, go for something purely turnbased next and jsut burry this one silently.

Comment: @Christopher, What 3 options are you referring to? I am curious

Comment: @EmrahSüngü: These 3: https://www.microsoft.com/net/apps/gaming

Answer (score 0):

I tried it only out of curiosity.

Here is a small example how to run a application and get keys entered by user:

```
static void Main()
{
  StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(10);
  var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
  while (endTime > DateTime.Now)
  {
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
      ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
      msg.Append(key.KeyChar);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1);
    Console.Write("\r Enter the message within {0} seconds; message = {1}", (endTime - DateTime.Now).Seconds, msg);
  }
}
```

But remember, there are many problems with this code. The happy scenario will work, but there are many things, that will cause problems *(non standard/not expected user behaviour is only one of possible problems)*.